# Login con password_verify

Tags: php, pdo, encriptación

He aplicado a las contraseñas encriptación mediante `password_hash()`.

Cuando intento hacer login usando `password_verify` no consigo acceder. Creo que el problema lo tengo en la parte de `$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` porque cuando hago un `var_damp($row)` este no devuelve nada.

Este es el código (método `CheckUser` de la clase `Usuario`).

```
public function CheckUser() {

        // Try and cacth para capturar errores
        try {

                // Guardamos la sentencia sql para sacar obtener al usuario de la base de datos
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ?';

                // Preparamos la consulta con la sentencia guardada en $sql usando el atributo de la clase Conexion
                $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

                // Evitamos inyección sql
                $user = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['user']));
                $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

                // Ligamos los parámetros de la consulta usando bindParam con lo que haya escrito el usuario en el formulario de login
                $query->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                // Ejecutamos la consulta
                $query->execute();

                $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

                    // Iniciamos sesión
                    session_start();

                    // Guardamos en la variable supergoblal el nombre de usuario
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['user'];

                    // Guardamos la cookie
                    include('cookie.php');
                    Cookie();

                    // Dirigimos al usuario a una página temporal para comprobar que funciona
                    header('location:../index.php');

                } else {

                    // Dirigimos al usuario de nuevo a la página de login
                    // header('location:../acceder.php');
                    echo var_dump($query->execute());
                }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            echo "Error en la ejecución de la consulta<br>";
            echo "Mensaje: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>";
            echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: La contraseña esta en la BBDD encriptada pero en tu query me parece que va en claro por lo que nunca encontrará registros.

Comment: ¿Tengo que pasarle antes el `password_verify`?

Comment: No, el password_verify esta bien, lo que tienes es que obtener el usuario sin preguntar por la password. SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?

Comment: Efectivamente es eso @Lithorell, acabo de cambiarlo y funciona. Si quieres lo añades como respuesta para que te puntúe. Gracias

Comment: Ya esta añadido ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que falla es la obtención del usuario ya que la password de la BBDD esta encriptada y al hacer la query la compruebas contra una en claro. Asi es como debería funcionar

```
public function CheckUser() {

    // Try and cacth para capturar errores
    try {

            // Guardamos la sentencia sql para sacar obtener al usuario de la base de datos
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?';

            // Preparamos la consulta con la sentencia guardada en $sql usando el atributo de la clase Conexion
            $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

            // Evitamos inyección sql
            $user = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['user']));
            $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

            // Ligamos los parámetros de la consulta usando bindParam con lo que haya escrito el usuario en el formulario de login
            $query->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            // Ejecutamos la consulta
            $query->execute();

            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

                // Iniciamos sesión
                session_start();

                // Guardamos en la variable supergoblal el nombre de usuario
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['user'];

                // Guardamos la cookie
                include('cookie.php');
                Cookie();

                // Dirigimos al usuario a una página temporal para comprobar que funciona
                header('location:../index.php');

            } else {

                // Dirigimos al usuario de nuevo a la página de login
                // header('location:../acceder.php');
                echo var_dump($query->execute());
            }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "Error en la ejecución de la consulta<br>";
        echo "Mensaje: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>";
        echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine();

    }
}
```