# Problema en login con password_verify()

Tags: php, login, backend

reciban un cordial saludo y gracias de antemano por sus respuestas; como indica el título, el problema se presenta al querer comparar una contraseña proveniente del login con la contraseña que ya está guardada en mi bd y encriptada con anticipación a través del registro de usuario, colocaré porciones de código para mayor comprensión, primero les explico como encripté la contraseña y el tipo de algoritmo utilizado:

Controlador "Registro" (Encriptando contraseña)

```
$contrasena  = password_hash($_POST['contrasena'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Instanciando y utilizando un método de la clase Registro

```
    $objeto    = new Registro;
    $respuesta = $objeto->registrarUsuario($cedula, $username, $contrasena, 
    $correo, $claveAcceso, $idRol);
```

Modelo "Registro"

```
    public function registrarUsuario($cedula, $username, $contrasena, $correo, $claveAcceso, $idRol)
{
    $query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (cod_usuario, username, password, email, clave_acceso, rol_id, status) VALUES (:cedula, :username, :contrasena, :correo, :claveAcceso, :idRol, 1)';

    try {

        $PDOStatement = Conexion::prepare($query);

        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':cedula', $cedula, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':username', $username, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':correo', $correo, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':claveAcceso', $claveAcceso, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':idRol', $idRol, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $PDOStatement->execute();

        return 'Registro Exitoso';

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

Hasta acá todo bien, debo hacer una pausa para comentarles que *el campo de mi entidad donde guardo la contraseña encriptada posee una longitud de 255 caracteres.*

**Una vez registrado el usuario procedo a trabajar sobre el login y acá viene el detalle:**

Controlador "Login"

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $cedula       = $_POST['letra_cedula'] . $_POST['cedula'];
    $contrasena   = $_POST['contrasena'];

    $objeto = new Login;
    $usuariosRegistrados = $objeto->obtenerUsuariosRegistrados($cedula);

    print_r($usuariosRegistrados);

    if ($usuariosRegistrados != NULL) {

        foreach ($usuariosRegistrados as $valor) {

            if ($cedula == $valor['cod_usuario'] && password_verify($contrasena, $valor['password'])) {



                print_r($valor['password']);

            } 

        }

    } else {

        echo $autenticacion = 'Cédula o contraseña incorrectos';

    }
   }
```

Reconozco que la variable ***$contraseña*** no la estoy utilizando, lo que sucede es que ando realizando distintos tipos de pruebas para hallar la solución pero no he tenido éxito, me apoyé en la siguiente fuente:

[Login con password_verify](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74984/login-con-password-verify?rq=1)

Modelo Login

```
    public function obtenerUsuariosRegistrados($cedula)
{
    $query = 'SELECT cod_usuario, password FROM usuarios WHERE cod_usuario = :cedula';

    try {

        $PDOStatement = Conexion::prepare($query);

        $PDOStatement->bindParam(':cedula', $cedula, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //$PDOStatement->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $PDOStatement->execute();
        return $usuariosRegistrados = $PDOStatement->fetchAll();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

**Cualquier sugerencia y/o ayuda será bien recibida, más información en caso de que la necesiten:**

PHP 7.3.1 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 22:43:14) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: Si haces una búsqueda por cédula en `$objeto->obtenerUsuariosRegistrados($cedula)`, ¿por qué luego compruebas que la cédula coincida con el código de usuario al comprobar la contraseña en `if ($cedula == $valor['cod_usuario'] ...`?

Comment: Cual es el problema exactamente, que error te arroja o hasta donde llega el Script. A simple vista no detecto nada estaño.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por sus respuestas. Logré solucionar el problema aplicando la lógica del siguiente vídeo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6I1p2DlxYM&t=324s

Sin embargo, después de realizar varias pruebas, increíblemente funcionó prácticamente como estaba antes (como lo había publicado acá). Realmente no reconozco qué fue lo que sucedió, pero dejo los pasos realizados por si le sirve a alguien más:

1. Me aseguré con `var_dump()` que la contraseña encriptada llegaba bien a mi controlador.
2. Apliqué la lógica del vídeo al traer la contraseña encriptada y usar la función `password_verify()`.
3. Fui al gestor de bbdd *pgadmin* y cambié la longitud de mi campo llamado `password` de 255 a 60 caracteres con tipo de dato `character varying` (`VARCHAR`).

Para este punto funcionaba todo increíble, es excelente pero acá viene lo extraño: posteriormente me di a la tarea de realizar una última prueba y colocar prácticamente el mismo código que publiqué acá y también funcionó. Aún estoy averiguando el por qué de esto.

Coloco cómo quedó el código:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $cedula       = $_POST['letra_cedula'] . $_POST['cedula'];
    $contrasena   = $_POST['contrasena'];

    $objeto = new Login;
    $usuariosRegistrados = $objeto->obtenerUsuariosRegistrados($cedula);

    //Recorremos registros obtenidos de la bd y lo comparamos con lo que hemos recibido del Frontend
    if ($usuariosRegistrados != NULL) {

        foreach ($usuariosRegistrados as $valor) {

            if ($contrasena == password_verify($contrasena, $valor['password'])) {

                    /*Redirección al index, pasamos la variable url con valor 'home' vía GET, así una vez que
                    /* el usuario se logee entrará en la interfaz home y se podrá visualizar la posición actual 
                    /* en la que se encuentra a través de la url
                    /*
                    /* Nota: Como estamos trabajando indexado y con jquery él capturará eso que envíamos vía GET,
                    /* él recibirá 'homeControlador', aquí envíamos 'home' y el archivo index le agrega el sufijo
                    /* 'Controlador' debido a esto se utiliza un condicional en el Frontend
                    */
                    header('Location:index.php?url=home');

            } else {

                echo $autenticacion = 'Cédula o contraseña incorrectos';

            }

        }

    } else {

        echo $autenticacion = 'Cédula o contraseña incorrectos';

    }
}
```

Si prestamos atención al condicional en donde se valida la contraseña que viene del login y la que está encriptada se darán cuenta que antepuse la variable `$contraseña` al comparar (eso no estaba). Sin embargo, sin anteponer esa variable funciona igualmente... cosas de la vida.

Gracias a [@franmost](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/41813/franmost) por la sugerencia de reducir código.

Comment: NOTA: Se me pasó el cuarto paso, luego de cambiar la longitud del campo "password" de 255 caracteres a 60 realicé otra prueba pero de manera invertida, cambiar longitud de 60 a 255 como estaba en un principio, y... funcionó...

Comment: Ese `if` me pareció muy raro e incoherente. Ha sido un placer ser de ayuda.